# SharePoint 2013 - Custom list view template and ECB Menu

Tags: 2013, list-view

I edited the default "All Items" view that was created when the list was added, to hide most of the ECB menu options. I also added a new feature that adds new items to the ECB menu for this specific list. It works exactly how I want it to on the All Items view.

When I create a new view starting from an existing view (the All Items view that I modified), the custom ECB menu options that I created are still there but the options that I have hidden on the All Items view, are back in the newly created view.

I want to be able to create new views and use the same modifications to the ECB menu that are applied to my customized All Items view, without having to go in to each newly created view and modify the ECB code.

Is there a way to do this? 
Is there some base list view template that I need to modify to stop the default options from being created? 
Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Thanks for any help.